# SQL Azure VM Cannot Connect

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, cloud, azure

I have SQL Azure VM

Following are the configuration of the VM

```
SIZE Basic_A1 (1 core, 1.75 GB memory)
```

After few hours I cannot log into server using any of following methods.

- Remote Desktop Connection
- SQL Connection

***But once I restart the server using Azure Portal Control panel again I can log into the server.

Seems like after few hours server is getting freeze,can't understand what it is. Plesae any suggestion for an investigation

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing the VM, then you can change it back if desired. This will hopefully fix the issue. If not, then you may need to try to fix the issue by removing the virtual machine (hitting delete in the portal) and re-deploying it using the same VHD disk that you used. You will also need to re-attach any data disks you were using as well. This will appear like a hard "reboot" to the Virtual Machine. This re-creation of the VM can be accomplished by going through the create VM process in the portal, selecting gallery, and from there selecting "My Disks."

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/cae5d9d5-65a3-41b7-83d6-3cc24c418c18/vm-becomes-unresponsive-or-disk-becomes-readonly?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Comment: Thanx for the comment, do you have any idea why this happens

Comment: @las Not sure exactly but it may be because the disk is going into a read-only state for some reason. I think it's an issue on Azure's end, not anything you can control. Looks like this has been an ongoing issue since 2012: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/3a8bad53-3b0b-4fcb-8401-424064e87b73/virtual-machines-often-hang?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Comment: Thanx a lot for the link, feeling like its something with the azure